# Writing a specific format of time in a text file every minute using Cron

Tags: command-line, scripts, printing, cron, date

I'm rather new to Linux. I recently wanted to learn how to work with Cron. So I wrote the following line to crontab file and it worked:

`* * * * * date >> //home/os/system-date.txt`

This line will append the current date and time in `system-date.txt` every minute.

When I run the following command in terminal, time is printed in a specific format:

`date +"%H-%M-%S"`

For instance, `23-59-59` is printed.

But when I want to do this with Cron, nothing is written in the txt file. To be specific, when I write the following line in crontab

`* * * * * date +"%H-%M-%S" >> //home/os/system-date.txt`

nothing happens. I wonder why.

Comment: You may have a syntax error on the command line. Try to add `2>>/home/os/cron.err` to the end of the crontab entry to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks. I did but no cron.err file gets created. @FedonKadifeli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the percent (`%`) signs in your `crontab` entries with a backslash (`\`) like this:

```
* * * * * date +"\%H-\%M-\%S" >>/home/os/system-date.txt 2>>/home/os/system-date.err
```

Percent signs have a special meaning in `crontab` entries: They are interpreted as newline characters. Please, see the
[man page for crontab(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/crontab.5.html):

> The "sixth" field  (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or `%` character, will be executed by  `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the `crontab` file. Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (`\`), will be changed into  newline  characters, and all data after the first `%` will be sent to the command as standard input. There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "`\`".

Also, note that the command in a `crontab` entry *will not* be executed by `/bin/bash` normally. So, it is always a good practice to create a Bash script and call that Bash script from `crontab`. Another point to note is that the `PATH` environment variable is much simpler in a `crontab` executed command (or script), so it is again a good practice to use *full path names* for commands executed in a script which is written to be called by `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

Your could create a simple script file (i.e. addDate.sh) like:

```
#!/bin/bash
date +"%H-%M-%S" 2>&1 >> //home/os/system-date.txt
```

The `2>&1` redirects errors also to the specified outputfile.

and in your crontab run this script file.

```
* * * * * /myscripts/addDate.sh
```

Where `/myscripts` is the path where you saved your script file.